# Need Help in displaying Error Message on Same page

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, apex, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

I have craeted a trigger which will Fire on update on Field on campaign and restrict the user from leaving the Comments field blank upon rejecting the record.

Here is my trigger code:

```
trigger RequireRejectionComment on Campaign (before update)
{

    Map<Id, Campaign > rejectedStatements
            = new Map<Id, Campaign>{};

    for(Campaign inv: trigger.new)
    {

        Campaign oldInv = System.Trigger.oldMap.get(inv.Id);

        if ((oldInv.BR_ApprovalStatusRegulatory__c != 'Reprovado'
            && inv.BR_ApprovalStatusRegulatory__c == 'Reprovado')||
            (oldInv.BR_ApprovalStatusLegal__c!= 'Reprovado' && 
                inv.BR_ApprovalStatusLegal__c== 'Reprovado') )
        {
            rejectedStatements.put(inv.Id, inv);
        }


    }

    if (!rejectedStatements.isEmpty())
    {

        List<Id> processInstanceIds = new List<Id>{};

        for (Campaign invs : [SELECT (SELECT ID
                                       FROM ProcessInstances
                                       ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                                      LIMIT 1)
                               FROM Campaign
                               WHERE ID IN :rejectedStatements.keySet()])
        {
            processInstanceIds.add(invs.ProcessInstances[0].Id);
        }

        // Now that we have the most recent process instances, we can check
        // the most recent process steps for comments.
        for (ProcessInstance pi : [SELECT TargetObjectId,
                                          (SELECT Id, StepStatus, Comments
                                            FROM Steps
                                            ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
                                           LIMIT 1 )
                                    FROM ProcessInstance
                                    WHERE Id IN :processInstanceIds
                                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC])
        {
            if ((pi.Steps[0].Comments == null ||
                pi.Steps[0].Comments.trim().length() == 0))
            {
                Trigger.new[0].parentId.addError(' My error Message  ');
                //rejectedStatements.get(pi.TargetObjectId).addError(
                // ' My error Message');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This trigger works fine but it displays an error message on new page..

**My requirement**: Error message should appear on record or the same page, while rejecting the record.

Please suggest,thanks..

Comment: Hi Guys Any idea on this??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating the validation within the apex page itself?

You can set the page item to have a validation that doesn't allow the page to be submitted if a specified page item is NULL.

Look for the validations section within the page-processing section when editing your page.

Here is a link to documentation regarding validations:

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/HTMDB/bldr_validate.htm#HTMDB28931

Comment: Hi Jashelb, thanks for your response on this..Is this is some external tool that you are pointing here for creating Validation or its withing salesforce i can implement this??

Comment: Apologies, I misread the tags as a reference to Oracle Apex as opposed to Salesforce apex-code.

Having a quick look however, these pages should be able to give you some assistance.

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_useful_field_validation_formulas.htm